# Leaflet highlight feature by ID

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a map application where:

1. I load polygons as GeoJSON objects
2. I draw all polygons in a single layer
3. I highlight a polygon on mouse hover

What I need to do is the following: on mouse hover, I need to highlight multiple polygons (I get the list of polygons somehow - irrelevant -). I have the IDs of all the polygons I need to highlight, but I can't see how can I access them though the API.

Comment: this might be useful http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html

Comment: I already used this as a basis. What I need now is to control the visual appearance of each polygon programmatically ... calling them by their IDs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to store polygon IDs in `onEachFeature(feature, layer)` handler (e.g. `layer._polygonId = feature.id`), so later you can iterate over layers (e.g. `jsonLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) { setHighlighted(layer, doesRelate(layer._polygonId, selectedId)); });`.