# Highlighting feature by Id with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I cannot work out the solution given in [Leaflet highlight feature by ID](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102947).

I have the script below which adds a layer "commercial" and a layer "sector". What I want is that when I mouseover a commercial, its corresponding sector highlights (they have the same Id). So I added _featureId on both layers and I am stuck.

What do I need to do to make it work?

```
        var json_commercial = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "name": "commercial",
        "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
        "features": [
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.305263516194724, 49.42360636638827 ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "2" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.974762218487792, 49.283373530097158 ] } }
        ]
    }

    var json_secteurs = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "name": "secteurs",
        "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
        "features": [
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "1" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 1.020274203732134, 49.305991729498949 ], [ 1.309787156075082, 49.56836284255975 ], [ 1.789292983393091, 49.455271845550783 ], [ 1.020274203732134, 49.305991729498949 ] ] ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "2" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 1.789292983393091, 49.455271845550783 ], [ 1.309787156075082, 49.56836284255975 ], [ 1.775722063752015, 49.65883564016692 ], [ 1.789292983393091, 49.455271845550783 ] ] ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "3" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 1.789292983393091, 49.455271845550783 ], [ 1.775722063752015, 49.65883564016692 ], [ 2.318558849395044, 49.305991729498949 ], [ 1.689772906025202, 49.002907857514927 ], [ 1.789292983393091, 49.455271845550783 ] ] ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "4" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 1.789292983393091, 49.455271845550783 ], [ 1.689772906025202, 49.002907857514927 ], [ 1.020274203732134, 49.305991729498949 ], [ 1.789292983393091, 49.455271845550783 ] ] ] ] } }
        ]
    }

    var map = L.map('mapid').setView([49.4, 1.3], 8);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        accessToken: 'mypk'
    }).addTo(map);

    var myStyle = {
        "color": "#bb7800",
        "weight": 5,
        "opacity": 0.65
    };

    var commercial = L.geoJSON(json_commercial, {
        style: myStyle,
        onEachFeature: storeFeatureId
    }).addTo(map);


    var secteur = L.geoJSON(json_secteurs, {
        style: myStyle,
        onEachFeature: storeFeatureId
    }).addTo(map);


    function storeFeatureId(feature, layer) {
        layer._featureId = feature.properties.id
    }


    function highlightSecteur(e) {
        if (secteur._featureId = e.layer._featureId) {
            secteur.setStyle ({color: '#ffff00'});
        }
    }

    function resetStyle() {
        secteur.setStyle({color: "#bb7800"});
    }

    commercial.on('mouseover',highlightSecteur);
    commercial.on('mouseout',resetStyle);
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a point-in-polygon query, either when needed (when clicking) or in advance (precalculate data, create a map of point IDs to the ID of the polygon containing it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above code there are several things wrong or unnecessary.

First, there is no need to store feature id `feature.properties.id` in the layer object, since it can be always retrieved through layer properties with `layer.feature.properties.id`.

Second, when you are trying to compare features id in `highlightSecteur` function,
your are using single `=` operator, so you are actually assigning value `e.layer._featureId` to `secteur._featureId` and consequently result of test is always true, since id's are not `null`.

Third, even if your comparison operator in `highlightSecteur` function would be correct `==`, logic wouldn't work, since `secteur` is group layer, containing all feature layers.

As @IvanSanchez wrote in his comment, there are two approaches possible to make this work.

On is to iterate through all feature layers of `secteur` layer when doing comparison in `highlightSecteur` and compare feature id's. In this case relevant code could look something like this:

```
var commercial = L.geoJSON(json_commercial, {
  style: myStyle,
}).addTo(map);

var secteur = L.geoJSON(json_secteurs, {
  style: myStyle,
}).addTo(map);

var selectedLayer;

function highlightSecteur(e) {
  secteur.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    if (layer.feature.properties.id == e.layer.feature.properties.id) {
      layer.setStyle({color: '#ffff00'});
      selectedLayer = layer;
      return;
    }
  });
}

function resetStyle() {
  selectedLayer.setStyle({color: "#bb7800"});
}

commercial.on('mouseover',highlightSecteur);
commercial.on('mouseout',resetStyle);
```

The other approach is to store individual feature layers of `secteur` in an array where index is feature id. This way there is no need to loop through all the feataure layers when doing comparison, instead feature layer can be referenced by it's id. In this case code could look something like this:

```
var featureLayers = new Array();
var selectedLayer;

function storeFeatureLayer(feature, layer) {
  featureLayers[parseInt(feature.properties.id)] = layer;
}

function highlightSecteur(e) {
  selectedLayer = featureLayers[parseInt(e.layer.feature.properties.id)];
  selectedLayer.setStyle({color: '#ffff00'});
}

function resetStyle() {
  selectedLayer.setStyle({color: "#bb7800"});
}

var commercial = L.geoJSON(json_commercial, {
  style: myStyle,
}).addTo(map);

var secteur = L.geoJSON(json_secteurs, {
  style: myStyle,
  onEachFeature: storeFeatureLayer
}).addTo(map);

commercial.on('mouseover',highlightSecteur);
commercial.on('mouseout',resetStyle);
```

Comment: Thank you. I used your second approach. It works perfectly !